# YTM calculation of a portfolio

Tags: fixed-income, yield, yield-futures

Should I take in count future which are used to lower the duration to calculate the portfolio's YTM ?
(Bloomberg calculate portfolio's YTM without Future)

Im currently doing the weighted average. I also take in count future.

[image: 1]

If the calculation change with future, what would be the correct formula ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take the implied yield to maturity of the future (field on BBG: FUT_CTD_EQV_YLD ) and put it in the formula, with the relevant weight.